# How to save my album as JPEG on Kodak Digi Album Pro?

Tags: photoshop, jpeg, windows-7, kodak

**Objective:**
Save my album as JPEG on Kodak Digi Album Pro.

I am using Kodak Digi Album pro and I'm new to this tool. This program generates a .PAB and .KPL file format, but I want my images to be saved in the JPEG format.

Is there a way to convert my .PAB and .KPL files to JPEG?

Answer (score 1):

> I am using Kodak Digi Album pro and I'm new to this tool.

**Kodak Digi Album appears to be dead software.** There appear to be no *real* references to the software in standard search engines. (Results consist mainly of references to this page and fake download sites.) Searching [Kodak Support](https://support.en.kodak.com) also returns no relevant results.

> Is there a way to convert my .PAB and .KPL files to JPEG?

If the software does not provide built-in export, **what you want may not be possible.** There do not appear to be any existing converters, and it is unlikely anyone will create one in the future because the software is no longer available.